# How to use intervals in SWITCH function in Excel

Tags: excel, switch-statement

I am trying to give automated name for growth I have in percent value. For example, if it's 0% to 30% then it's "slow growth", if it's 30% to 70% then it's "healthy growth" and so on. I have 8 possible cases both wit growth and decline. And decline is defined when there are negative values (with "-"). As I have very big table, I want to do this with SWITCH formula.

Here is my trial formula, but it already does not do the job.

```
=SWITCH(I2, (0%-30%), "slow", (30%-70%), "healthy", (70%-100%), "rapid",
(100%-1000000%),"aggressive",(0%-30%), "slow", (30%-70%), "healthy", 
(70%-100%), "rapid",(100%-1000000%),"aggressive" "??")
```

Right now for all values I get "??" which is the option for not being in any of the intervals.

I think that the problem is with the way I indicate value intervals. First problem is that I don't get any values for these intervals. Second problem would arise when I would have negative values with "-". Which brings me to my question - is it possible and if yes, how to use intervals in switch function?

Comment: I am surprised you get even that as i wasn't aware SWITCH existed as an Excel worksheet function.

Comment: You also have overlaps in your intervals

Comment: @QHarr, yes, in recent versions of Excel they introduced it.
And thanks for noticing overlaps!

Comment: some homework for me!

Comment: Also, is one set of values intended to be negative to represent decline?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. And therefore I don't know how to show intervals as here I use "-" to indicate "to", but when there are negatives values, that indicates minus.

Comment: Maybe add in the question text description that the ranges are negative for decline.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks, that is important, yes!